# "Juntar" dois grafos em R

Tags: r, grafo

Estou usando a biblioteca `igraph` para criar dois grafos no R:

```
g.v1 <- graph.full(6, directed= TRUE)
E(g.v1)$weight <- 1

g.merchant <- graph.empty(1, directed=TRUE)
E(g.merchant)$weight <- 1
```

Este dois grafos, `g.v1` e `g.merchant`, são disjuntos. Eu gostaria de conectar o grafo `g.merchant`, que só tem 1 vértice, com qalquer um dos 6 vértices do grafo `g.v1`. O novo grafo terá 7 vértices. Como faço isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código abaixo resolve o teu problema. Inclusive, ele seleciona aleatoriamente um dos vértices do `g.v1` para fazer a ligação com o grafo `g.merchant`.

```
library(igraph)

g.v1 <- graph.full(6, directed= TRUE)
E(g.v1)$weight <- 1
plot(g.v1)
```

[image: g.v1]

```
g.merchant <- graph.empty(1, directed=TRUE)
E(g.merchant)$weight <- 1
plot(g.merchant)
```

[image: g.merchant]

```
g.novo <- g.v1 + g.merchant
v.aleatorio <- sample(unique(V(g.v1)), 1)
g.novo <- g.novo + path(v.aleatorio, 7, v.aleatorio)
plot(g.novo)
```

[image: g.novo]

Note que no primeiro plot do `g.merchant`, seu único vértice foi identificado como 1. Ao juntar os dois grafos, o número deste vértice foi atualizado para 7.

Comment: Perfeito cara. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou, por favor vote nela e aceite-a. Assim os outros usuários do site poderão se beneficiar caso tenham a mesma dúvida.